# getting error message: “rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.” datastore + Appengine + Golang

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, google-app-engine-golang

In local system is working perfectly but when deployed to production using gcloud app deploy it is throwing error on every end point calling

**> message: "rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or

insufficient permissions."**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (when trying to migrate from Go 1.9 runtime to a newer runtime).
For me, "[app_name]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" was missing from the permissions.
The service account existed though, just not listed.
So, I added the service account and set the following permissions:

- App Engine Standard Environment Service Agent
- Cloud Datastore User

All worked again.

Answer (score 0):

See below answer which helped me..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033777/4481287

```
gcloud set project project-bar
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-bar --member serviceAccount:project-foo@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/datastore.user
```

Essentially you want to give your main google app engine service account, access to your firebase project